# Searching string values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I want to change some of the words of my string, S to some others based on the dictionary, D.
For example, for the following values of S and D:

```
S="I don't know, who you are?"
D={"doesn't":"does not","don't":"do not"}
```

I should get

```
S="I do not know, who you are?"
```

To do this, I am writing the following code:

```
L=str.split(' ')
index = [D[x] if x in D.keys() for x in L]
```

But this is giving syntax error. Kindly help me in resolving this error so that I am able to get the required output as shown above. If there is an even better solution to this problem, please explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the string value if the value is not in the dictionary.

```
result = ' '.join(D.get(x,x) for x in S.split(' '))
```

The reason for syntax error with `[D[x] if x in D.keys() for x in L]` is that `if` needs to go after `for` if there is no accompanying `else` condition. Look up the syntax in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: You don't need the `[]`, and with `dict.get(key, value if not found)`, you can do  `' '.join( D.get(i,i) for i in S.split(' ') )`

Comment: What I have found that the error occurs as I am not using *else*. Is it mandatory to use *else*? Why is that happening?

Comment: @Vamsi can you please re-write it in normal notation as shown in the documentation.

Comment: no, it should be `[D[x] for x in L if x in D.keys()]`

Comment: Can you please insert 'else' into this equation now, which you have just written?

Comment: `[D[x] if x in D.keys() else x for x in L]`

Answer (score 2):

You can check this one liner answer too:

```
S="I don't know, who you are?"
D={"doesn't":"does not","don't":"do not"}

result = ' '.join(map(lambda x: D[x] if D.get(x) else x, S.split()))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
'I do not know, who you are?'
```

Comment: Your `if/else` can be covered by `lambda x: D.get(x, x)`